# Calling getMetricsData cloudwatch API using boto3 in Lambda code returns access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am calling GetMetricData cloudwatch API using boto 3 Python in Lambda code, but getting access denied error.

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetMetricData operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/lambda_test15mins-role-88yy778/lambda_test15mins is not authorized to perform: cloudwatch:GetMetricData",

Any help would be appreciated!

### Here is the code used

```
import json

import logging

import os

import boto3

import datetime

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client(service_name='cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-2')
    response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'CMS_API',
                    'MetricName': 'API_Endpoint_Errors_Metrics',
                    'Dimensions': [
                       
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 2000,
                'Stat': 'Sum',
                'Unit': 'Count'
            }
        },
    ],
    StartTime= datetime.datetime.now(),
    EndTime= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    NextToken='string',
    ScanBy='TimestampDescending',
    MaxDatapoints=123,
    LabelOptions={
        'Timezone': 'string'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to your `lambda execution role`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have created an IAM user & added AdministratorAccess policy & additionally added the Inline policy suggested in the solution. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @vilasgurav This means that your code runs under different IAM user/role then you think. You have to double check this.

Comment: @vilasgurav Its not clear what you are you doing. There is no need for Policy Simulator . Just identify IAM user/role under which your code runs.

Comment: The metrics are created with one role  & the lambda is created with another role & the logged-in user has access to both roles. 

What should be the next step since 2 roles are involved.

Comment: I created a role with full access to cloudwatch & assigned it to lambda function. This worked